# How do I restore the Windows (8.1) MBR from Ubuntu Linux

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, windows, grubrescue, mbr

Not so new to Ubuntu but when it comes to the internal advanced workings I'm completely lost.

It seems to be a common issue to delete your Ubuntu partition from Windows and find out later that you've been shoved into GRUB Rescue instead of being able to boot into Windows. I know there are different entries out there with the same question but I'm not getting an answer I can use.

So maybe if I re-word things someone might be able to give me a layman answer.

From my understanding the computer in question (HP G62-465DX (an evil machine)) does not support USB booting. I could be wrong so if I am **please point me in the direction I'd need to take to restore the Windows MBR via USB**. I have no access to any recovery CDs or blank ones of any kind (and it will be some time before I can get my hands on a blank one. In case I do, however, if someone could please tell me, again from Ubuntu, how to **restore the MBR from a CD (I would, again, need to set everything up in UBUNTU because I have no machines with Windows access**).

At this time, if the USB option is a no-go, my only viable option is somehow using another computer with Ubuntu (14.10), a hard drive reader, my Windows hard drive, and a programme that might be able to help me. I tried installing EasyBCD via Wine but there was an error during the installation.

So, if possible, outside USBs and CDs what are my options with what I have? If not, and if that vile dinosaur can't boot from USB, what steps do I need to take with a CD outside a Windows environment.

Sorry if this post was jumbled, I don't do well with forums. If any clarification is needed please don't hesitate to ask. Thank you for taking the time to read this and inputting answers if you can.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if Windows 8.1 MBR can be recovered with it ... but boot-repair helped me out a lot with other windows versions:

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair

- startup with ubuntu live usb/iso/...
- connect to internet
- open terminal

  - $ sudo add-apt-repository ppa:yannubuntu/boot-repair
  - $ sudo apt-get update
  - $ sudo apt-get install -y boot-repair && boot-repair

Comment: Thank you for your method of using boot repair as a means to restoring the MBR. I will attempt it if my computer allows USB booting. At this time, however, I am not sure if it does. I'm attempting to make a bootable USB but every programme (including Unebootin) that I've used for Ubuntu leave the stick unbootable. Startup Disc Creator always crashes at the last minute and says it failed to install the boot loader.

In my original post, I also asked for alternatives. Specifically what I might be able to do with a hard drive reader and a secondary computer housing Ubuntu. Unmountable hibernation

Comment: At least try to have a bootable usb stick. For me Ubuntu Desktop is more than enough. I always carry it with me on my key chain. Then with USB inserted, go to the BIOS to choose the startup disk. If this BIOS gives you problems, you can put your disk in the secondary pc, and use the USB and BIOS there to try to startup your Live Ubuntu USB.

Comment: Certainly a few times a year, I try out something that breaks the whole startup of my system, ... 1 usb stick at home, 1 usb stick on my key chain ... and it saved me sooo much.  Boot-repair, mount disk and fix configuration, ...     In ubuntu, use Startup Disk Creator, ... For unetbootin, i always download the ISO first ... or http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/create-a-usb-stick-on-windows ... or http://www.howtogeek.com/127377/the-best-free-tools-for-creating-a-bootable-windows-or-linux-usb-drive/